# How can I give this table rounded borders and still maintain the color scheme I have?

Tags: html, css

I'd prefer not to use tables while doing this, but I don't know how else to go about it. Basically, I want a table with alternating white & grey rows. The table needs to have a rounded border and there should be borders in between the individual rows (but NO column borders).

Here's what I've got so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/zVDyh/1/

Even though I am setting the border radius, it doesn't seem to affect the table's border at all.

Comment: There's an answer here about this already.

Check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628301/css3s-border-radius-property-and-border-collapsecollapse-dont-mix-how-can-i

Comment: simplest solution may be to style the table as you want it without an outer border. Put the entire table into a DIV and give the DIV rounded corners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it with DIVs:

http://jsfiddle.net/RRd2e/

```
<div class="con">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">c1</div>
        <div class="col">c2</div>
        <div class="col">c3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">c1</div>
        <div class="col">c2</div>
        <div class="col">c3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">c1</div>
        <div class="col">c2</div>
        <div class="col">c3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">c1</div>
        <div class="col">c2</div>
        <div class="col">c3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">c1</div>
        <div class="col">c2</div>
        <div class="col">c3</div>
    </div>
</div>

.con {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.row { 
    height: 38px; 
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; 
}
.row:nth-child(even) {
     background:#e3e3e3;
}
.row:last-child {
    border-bottom:none;
}
.col { 
    width:50px; 
    line-height:38px; 
    display:inline; 
}
```

Comment: You could use divs, but the data is really calling for a table, and I'd suggest one uses a table for it.

Comment: I agree, data output requires tables.  The OP mentioned he would like to use divs and I was a bit bored so I threw the sample together.

Comment: Oh wow - thanks a lot, this is cool. I'm curious though - what do you mean "the data is calling for a table"?

Comment: When you are displaying tabular data on a web page it is best practice to use tables.  Really that is the one major case to use tables, mostly everything else should be contained in divs.

Answer (score 2):

Set a width and make it block display:

```
.my_table {
    border: 1px solid $grey;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
}
```

Here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zVDyh/4/)! :)

Comment: The width part isn't necessary, is it?

Comment: No but, if you remove it, it looks awkward... Better to set a width to contain the inner things. Yeah, width part is necessary!

Comment: So, not _necessary_ but a stylistic choice.

Comment: My opinion as a Front End Engineer would be it is necessary! :)

Comment: thanks Praveen! However, I'm seeing a problem here: there seems to be an inside border of some sort... as I increase the border radius, the inside border is more & more visible. I can also switch to using only divs, but that seems like it would be a pretty big headache. Sadly I can't get rid of this inside border though ...

Comment: Remove the border for the `td` and not for the `tr`! Check out: http://jsfiddle.net/zVDyh/13/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help Praveen Kumar + Lokase. This was the easiest answer for me to follow though: [CSS3's border-radius property and border-collapse:collapse don't mix. How can I use border-radius to create a collapsed table with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628301/css3s-border-radius-property-and-border-collapsecollapse-dont-mix-how-can-i)

It links to this page: http://vamin.net/examples/rounded_tables2.html (look at the last example - cellspacing = 0)