# css styling table issue

Tags: html, css

I have a question regarding the table style.

I want to have the table radius as 8px but it seems like my codes don't work. Can anyone help me about it?

Thanks!

//ps I need my `border-collapse.`

my jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/vfBtN/1/

Comment: Already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628301/css3s-border-radius-property-and-border-collapsecollapse-dont-mix-how-can-i

Answer (score 0):

Try    `border-spacing: 0;` instead of border-collpase. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vfBtN/4/)