# border-radius didn't apply to my table

Tags: css

i apply a border-radius to my table but it's not working

CSS :

```
table {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TExvf/)

PS. i want to use `border-collapse: collapse` not `border-collapse: separate`

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628301/css3s-border-radius-property-and-border-collapsecollapse-dont-mix-how-can-i

Comment: yes but it's not my case i think

Answer (score 4):

Did you try removing `border-collapse: collapse`?

```
table {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: and with `border-collapse` it's impossible ?

Comment: @Youssef use `border-spacing: 0; instead` of `border-collapse: collapse;`

Answer (score 2):

remove your `border-collapse`

```
table{
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: and with `border-collapse` it's impossible ?

Comment: @Youssef its collapsing the `border`, so most of the `border-` properties are likewise will not work, save for `border`because you are specifying it to have border.

Answer (score 0):

Edit this in your table:

```
table {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

And here is the edited fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/piyushkmr/TExvf/7/

Answer (score -3):

Box properties only works with DIV tag. you can do that if you want to create your table with DIV.

Comment: "Box properties only works with DIV tag." What do you mean? What are these box properties you refer to, and why only div?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.