# Table border is not giving the desire result

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a table with rounded corners AND a single solid border between `<tr>'s`. However, I seem to have a bit of a problem correctly using border-collapse.  When I set `border-collapse: separate`, I get the following:

**Result - border-collapse: separate**

[image: img]

**Code**

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            This
        </td>
        <td>
            that
        </td>
        <td>
            the other.
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            This
        </td>
        <td>
            that
        </td>
        <td>
            the other.
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table, tr {
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-collapse: separate;
 border-color: #ACACAC;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
```

However, when I use `border-collapse: collapse`, I get the correct line between the `<tr>'s` but the corners are not rounded, as see here:

**Result - border-collapse: collapse**

[image: img]

Does anyone know how to get both the line between the `<tr>'s` WITH the rounded corners?

Thanks so much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3's border-radius property and border-collapse:collapse don't mix. How can I use border-radius to create a collapsed table with rounded corners?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628301/css3s-border-radius-property-and-border-collapsecollapse-dont-mix-how-can-i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `cellpadding = 0 and cellspacing = 0` at the table element ,remove `border-bottom` of the tr elments and add this CSS `border-bottom` for all td elements except last one like:

```
tr:not(:last-child) td{    
  border-bottom:1pt solid #ACACAC; 
}
```

```css
table,
tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-color: #ACACAC;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
tr:not(:last-child) td {
  border-bottom: 1pt solid #ACACAC;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
  <tr>
    <td>
      This
    </td>
    <td>
      that
    </td>
    <td>
      the other.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      This
    </td>
    <td>
      that
    </td>
    <td>
      the other.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It is working :

http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/dngpq4hb/3/

Comment: You almost got it, but the border-bottom goes outside the rounded corner. Remove `border-bottom: none` from table and move td border-bottom to `tr:not(:last-child) td{}`

Comment: Dont forget that sometimes we are lost at this paradise and our brain will explode sometime :)