# How to set border radius to table border?

Tags: html, css

```css
table {
  width:100%;
}

table, td, tr {
  border: 1px #000000 solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

tr {
  height:50px;
}

.price {
  width: 65%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border-color: #c0c0c0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.buy {
  width:35%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #c0c0c0;

}
```

```html
<table>
          <tr>
            <td class="price">$180</td>
            <td class="buy">Buy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="price">$180</td>
            <td class="buy">Buy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="price">$180</td>
            <td class="buy">Buy</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

I try to set border-radius to my "td" but not working.

What I want it looks like is border of td of both right and left side is radius.

Is any way can do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628301/css3s-border-radius-property-and-border-collapsecollapse-dont-mix-how-can-i

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ywyzceks/1/) for you:

```
table {
    width:100%;
    background: #000;
    border: #000 1px solid;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
td, tr {
    border: 1px #000000 solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```