# Bootstrap table border radius won't work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to get curved corners on a table, however nothing is happening when I add border-radius. I've tried adding !important but it didn't help.

```
.table {
border: 3px solid #d8d8d8;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Thanks if someone can fix it

Comment: Your answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628301/css3s-border-radius-property-and-border-collapsecollapse-dont-mix-how-can-i)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an div around with class `panel`.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <table class="table table-bordered">
    &nbsp;
 </table>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/Ylama/pen/BJjBeq

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution

HTML :

```
<table class="table">
 <tr>
  <td>i am a good guy you think ? am i.....</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

CSS :

```
.table{
  border: 3px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/inewton/pen/JMGRVQ)