# Border radius and border together in a table td

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to give my first and last `<td>` a `border-radius` so that my table looks like a rounded table.

First I applied background to my `<td>` and then added `border-radius`, which works fine I think(background rounded from the corner).

After that when I applied border to my `<td>`, I saw a  weird thing(See below snippet).

So my question is why border is not rounded as background?

***Stack Snippet***

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  color: #ffffff;
}

table tbody tr:first-child td:first-child {
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 0;
}

table tbody tr:first-child td:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 20px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: a weird thing: You mean the table border? Yes, it is specified in the CSS for your table.

Comment: seems like border-collapse is whats preventing the corners to be rounded.

Comment: hey border-collapse and border-radius are enemies 
this might  help https://stackoverflow.com/q/628301/7354094

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS3's border-radius property and border-collapse:collapse don't mix. How can I use border-radius to create a collapsed table with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628301/css3s-border-radius-property-and-border-collapsecollapse-dont-mix-how-can-i)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try `border-collapse: inherit;` and make 'border-spacing: 0px;'

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: inherit;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  font: 13px Verdana;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-left: none;
}
table td:first-child{
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
}
table tbody tr:first-child td:first-child {
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 0;
}

table tbody tr:first-child td:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 20px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for response! but its giving me 2px border in middle of `td`

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt check now made it 1px border

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt table has default property border-collapse :separate; so inherit property ll inherit separate only so no problem or u can remove border-collapse :inherit; it ll work

Answer (score 2):

Please checkout this solution with first row and last row rounded.

HTML

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-radius: 20px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

table tr {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  color: #ffffff;
}

table tr:first-child td:first-child {
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 0;
}

table tr:first-child td:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 20px 0 0;
}

table tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 20px;
}

table tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 0;
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xwqjgb5k/

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for a solution in which border should be collapsed..not separate

Answer (score 0):

You can try by removing the  border-collapse: collapse; and add cellspacing & cellpadding zero to the table. Below code may help you

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
 
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  color: #ffffff;
}

table tbody tr:first-child td:first-child {
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 0;
}

table tbody tr:first-child td:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 20px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for response! but its giving me 2px border in middle of `td`

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

and set it to

```
  border-collapse: separate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout the updated solution.

```
<div class="table-wrapper">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

.table-wrapper {
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius: 20px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

table tr {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  color: #ffffff;
}

table tr:first-child td:first-child {
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 0;
}

table tr:first-child td:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 20px 0 0;
}

table tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 20px;
}

table tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 0;
}
```

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xwqjgb5k/1/

hope it will help you.