# Border radius on a table

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website for school and one of the requirements is to have a table element. I made a table element and set a border radius off 25 px. It turned out to have the borders remain a default radius and the background cut of on the corners.[Problem with borders image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acuuc.jpg) 
Here is the code i used:

```css
table {
  width: 750px;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid darkblue 5px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius: 25px
}
```

```html
<table style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
  <h2>Five Qualities</h2>
  <tr>
    <td>Creativity</td>
    <td>We want students here to be as creative as possible when planning out designs for their projects.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Inquiry</td>
    <td>We want students to ask as many meaningful questions as they can when they don't understand a subject or want to know more</td>
    </p>
    <tr>
      <td>Collaboration</td>
      <td>When working on a project, we want all students to collaborate with their partners of group members in order to make the most of their time during a project work-day.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Persistence</td>
      <td>When frustrated with a project, we want students to be persistent and keep working, even though they are frustrated.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Communication</td>
      <td>We want our students to communicate with their group or partners to get work done in a way that everybody agrees on.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628301/css3s-border-radius-property-and-border-collapsecollapse-dont-mix-how-can-i

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS3's border-radius property and border-collapse:collapse don't mix. How can I use border-radius to create a collapsed table with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628301/css3s-border-radius-property-and-border-collapsecollapse-dont-mix-how-can-i)

Answer (score 1):

use `border-spacing:0`  instead `border-collapse:collapse` to allow `border-radius` to be drawn.

```css
table {
  width: 750px;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid darkblue 5px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  border-spacing:0;
  border-radius: 25px
}
```

```html
<table style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
  <h2>Five Qualities</h2>
  <tr>
    <td>Creativity</td>
    <td>We want students here to be as creative as possible when planning out designs for their projects.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Inquiry</td>
    <td>We want students to ask as many meaningful questions as they can when they don't understand a subject or want to know more</td>
    </p>
    <tr>
      <td>Collaboration</td>
      <td>When working on a project, we want all students to collaborate with their partners of group members in order to make the most of their time during a project work-day.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Persistence</td>
      <td>When frustrated with a project, we want students to be persistent and keep working, even though they are frustrated.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Communication</td>
      <td>We want our students to communicate with their group or partners to get work done in a way that everybody agrees on.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
table {
  width: 750px;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid darkblue 5px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px
}
```

```html
<table style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
  <h2>Five Qualities</h2>
  <tr>
    <td>Creativity</td>
    <td>We want students here to be as creative as possible when planning out designs for their projects.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Inquiry</td>
    <td>We want students to ask as many meaningful questions as they can when they don't understand a subject or want to know more</td>
    </p>
    <tr>
      <td>Collaboration</td>
      <td>When working on a project, we want all students to collaborate with their partners of group members in order to make the most of their time during a project work-day.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Persistence</td>
      <td>When frustrated with a project, we want students to be persistent and keep working, even though they are frustrated.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Communication</td>
      <td>We want our students to communicate with their group or partners to get work done in a way that everybody agrees on.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How about an explanation to go along with your code dump?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this trick:
Give all the 4 cells at the corner of the table a class and then for each class set the border-radius like:

```
.top-left-cell { border-radius: 25px 0 0 0; }

.top-right-cell { border-radius: 0 25px 0 0; }

.bottom-right-cell { border-radius: 0 0 25px 0; }

.bottom-right-cell { border-radius: 0 0 0 25px; }
```