# How to create rounded corners on a table and keep table border for the whole table and columns?

Tags: html, css

I need to create a table with rounded corners and within the table only columns borders. There should be no border between the rows.

I tried to create the rounded corners but the collapse property should be collapse or the columns borders inside the table will be 2. If I keep the collapse property as separate as the other answers have suggested, the column borders will not collapse. I am not sure how to make this work.

```css
table {
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
  left: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000000 !important;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  border-left: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-right: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}
```

```html
<table class="status-table">
  <tr>
    <td>RA-STATUS</td>
    <td>Due Date</td>
    <td>Assigned To</td>
    <td>Last Updated</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Open-Draft</td>
    <td>04/20/2012</td>
    <td>John Doe(for you)</td>
    <td>03/28/2012 | By: John Doe</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you show design, you want to look like

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS3's border-radius property and border-collapse:collapse don't mix. How can I use border-radius to create a collapsed table with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628301/css3s-border-radius-property-and-border-collapsecollapse-dont-mix-how-can-i)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please use the search function first. Your question has already be asked multiple times adn have plenty of solutions on SO already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628301/css3s-border-radius-property-and-border-collapsecollapse-dont-mix-how-can-i --- As such your question will be flagged as a duplicate and closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rounded corners on a table and borders for columns

```css
table {
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    left: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

th,
td {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

td {
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
}

td:first-child {
    border-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table class="status-table">
    <tr>
        <td>RA-STATUS</td>
        <td>Due Date</td>
        <td>Assigned To</td>
        <td>Last Updated</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Open-Draft</td>
        <td>04/20/2012</td>
        <td>John Doe(for you)</td>
        <td>03/28/2012 | By: John Doe</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```