# Show products in a box with custom borders

Tags: css

I have a div (blue box) that need to show products in it. I have a component for product. As see in the below image

1. Products that show in the first row don't have top border
2. Products that show in the last row don't have bottom border
3. Products that show in the first column don't have left border
4. Products that show in the last column don't have right border

How can I find out that each product is placed in which location that according to that show appropriate borders?

[image]

Comment: It seems your looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2586780/21370707).

Comment: @Newbee I don't use table, I use div and flex.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question - [ask] - How to create a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood your requirement, you need ***[`nth-child selector with function notations`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)***. Something like:

```html
<style>
  .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    gap: 10px;
  }
  
  .product {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  
  .product:nth-child(4n+1) {
    border-left: none;
  }
  
  .product:nth-child(4n) {
    border-right: none;
  }
  
  .product:nth-child(-n+4) {
    border-top: none;
  }
  
  .product:nth-last-child(-n+4) {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
</style>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="product" style="grid-column-start: 1; grid-column-end: 2;">Product 1</div>
  <div class="product" style="grid-column-start: 2; grid-column-end: 3;">Product 2</div>
  <div class="product" style="grid-column-start: 3; grid-column-end: 4;">Product 3</div>
  <div class="product" style="grid-column-start: 4; grid-column-end: 5;">Product 4</div>
  <div class="product" style="grid-column-start: 1; grid-column-end: 2;">Product 5</div>
  <div class="product" style="grid-column-start: 2; grid-column-end: 3;">Product 6</div>
  <div class="product" style="grid-column-start: 3; grid-column-end: 4;">Product 7</div>
  <div class="product" style="grid-column-start: 4; grid-column-end: 5;">Product 8</div>
  <div class="product" style="grid-column-start: 1; grid-column-end: 2;">Product 9</div>
  <div class="product" style="grid-column-start: 2; grid-column-end: 3;">Product 10</div>
  <div class="product" style="grid-column-start: 3; grid-column-end: 4;">Product 11</div>
  <div class="product" style="grid-column-start: 4; grid-column-end: 5;">Product 12</div>

  <!-- Repeat for other rows -->
</div>
```

Here if you notice I used function notation around multiples of `4` since my grid is having `4` products in each row but you can play around with it as per your specific requirement.

Comment: @mandy8055 Thank you, a problem that I have:  if the size of box will change according to the screen size, we don't know the number of products that show in each row.

Comment: @JohnS welcome. For the query that would be achievable. I could think of one way 
 which is to maintain a **[css variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)** in the html document to get to know the total number of products that will appear dynamically and based on that value write your css selector

Comment: @JohnS You can also maintain the `viewport-width` somewhere and based on that you can use called ***[`calc`](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-calc-in-css/)*** to get dynamically how much products will fit in a row based on screen size and get to your requirement. I haven't tried that but my instinct tells me that with some tinkering and based on your **exact requirement** it can be achieved.